# [python]; How can i write two variables, in same line but different column, in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to write 2 variables in same line but different columns. But i couldn't figure it out.

```
def SaveFile(point_que,real_distance):  
  file = open(file_name+'.csv',"a")

  #file.write('%s , %s' % (point_que, str(real_distance)))
  file.write(str(point_que))
  file.write(str(real_distance))
  file.write("\n")
  file.close()
```

One loop point_que=1 and real_distance=1350
 and the output is 11350 written in the same column. But i want to seperate this values different columns

Comment: What's wrong with the line you commented out? That's actually the way to write values in two columns

Comment: when i run the cod it will write same columnd. I want to have 2 column, One of them is point_que the other one is real_distance

Comment: try with f.write("%s %s\n" % (str(point_que), str(real_distance)))

Comment: İts not working. İ try it but its written same column like " 1 1350"